# Date localization with Jest unit test

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

The following unit test fails because the date is in english, i.e. "Friday, June 16, 2017" instead of the expected Dutch version, which would be "vrijdag 16 juni 2017".

```
 test('returns dutch version of date when given ISO version', () => {
    const dateToFormat = new Date('2017-06-16');

    const options = {
        weekday: 'long',
        year: 'numeric',
        month: 'long',
        day: 'numeric',
    };

    const result = new Intl
        .DateTimeFormat('nl-NL', options)
        .format(dateToFormat);

    expect(result).toBe('vrijdag 16 juni 2017');
 });
```

Why is this unit test failing?

Environment:

- Node.js: 6.11.0
- npm: 3.10.10
- Jest: 18.1.0
- OS: Ubuntu 16.04

Log of failing unit test:

```
FAIL  [path-to-file]
  returns dutch version of date when given ISO version

    expect(received).toBe(expected)

    Expected value to be (using ===):
      "vrijdag 16 juni 2017"
    Received:
      "Friday, June 16, 2017"

      at Object.<anonymous> ([path-to-file]:15:20)
      at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
      at process.emit (events.js:191:7)
      at process.nextTick (internal/child_process.js:758:12)
      at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

Comment: I am looking a solution to the same problem. It seems that "Intl in Node" has a behaviour which is different from "Intl in the browser".